# Functionality change while upgrading to Castle Windsor 3.3.0 from 3.2.0

Tags: asp.net, castle-windsor, castle

I am attempting to migrate from version 3.2.0 to 3.3.0. I am getting a compile error. I could not find an entry in the "Breaking Changes" section but here are my two errors in hope someone can guide me to a workable alternative.

```
public void RegisterTypeSingleton<T>(Type component, string name)
{
    if (_container.Kernel.HasComponent(name))
        _container.Kernel.RemoveComponent(name);    
    _container.Register(Component.For<T>().ImplementedBy(component).Named(name).LifeStyle.Singleton);    
}
```

1. It seems `Kernel.RemoveComponent()` function has been depreciated. What has replaced this?
2. The second compiler error is at _`container.Register(Component.For<T>().ImplementedBy(component).Named(name).LifeStyle.Singleton);`

   - I am getting "The Type 'TService' must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be upgrading from an older version than 3.2.0. See below.

1. The removal of `IKernel.RemoveComponent()` is documented in the [Breaking Changes](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/BreakingChanges.txt) document with v3.0.0. Here is the extract where Krzysztof explains why it was removed:

   ```
   change - Removed the following methods:
       GraphNode.RemoveDepender,
       GraphNode.RemoveDependent,
       IKernel.RemoveComponent,
       IKernelEvents.ComponentUnregistered,
       INamingSubSystem.this[Type service],
       INamingSubSystem.GetHandler,
       INamingSubSystem.GetService2Handler,
       INamingSubSystem.GetKey2Handler,
       INamingSubSystem.UnRegister(String key),
       INamingSubSystem.UnRegister(Type service)
    Also INamingSubSystem.Register now takes only IHandler as its argument

   impact - low
   fixability - none

   description - The methods were implementation of "remove component from the container" feature
       which was flawed and problematic, hecen was scraped.

   fix - Working around is quite dependant on your specific usage. Try utilizing IHandlerSelectors.
       For changed Register method, just update your calling code not to pass the name.
       handler.ComponentModel.Name is now used as the key, as it was happening in all places so far
       anyway, so this change should have no real impact.
   ```

   `RegisterComponent()` won't overwrite an existing service registration, it'll just register another component for the same service, unless you specify the same name where it'll throw an exception informing you there is another component registered with that name. If your application doesn't replace components very often you could use the `IsDefault()` method on the registration to get Windsor to resolve the new component by default, just note the other component is still registered.

   If your application replaces components often and you don't want the other registrations left there, you'd be best using a custom `IHandlerSelector` or `ISubDependencyResolver` so Windsor will ask you each time what component you want used for a specific service.
2. Also in v3.0.0 [a change was made](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/commit/b1dd80db9de185ed6b0b222f8ae02a26dfcb3fc2) to ensure that [value types cannot be passed to the registration methods](http://issues.castleproject.org/youtrack/issue/IOC-267). You'll need to add a generic constraint to your method that accepts a generic parameter so that it also only accepts reference types:

   ```
   public void RegisterTypeSingleton<T>(Type component, string name)
       where T : class
   {
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess I was off on the version. Do you know if the RegisterComponet() will overwrite and existing registration with the same name and type and if not what would be the easiest way to remove an existing component prior to register? Thanks.

Comment: I've added an answer to your question and some more details into the answer above.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. I will have to think this over. I have a set of "Systems" that can be accessed during client login. Think of "System" as different database, server and service discovery process. For example I have a user login process where the user can log in against 1011 | 1112 | 1213 |1415  each has different server and connection info. The isDefault is set by the user and defaults to 1415. However, users can log into another box say 1112 that's where I need to teardown and buildup the new services. I will look into the best way to handle this.

Comment: I'd definitely use an IHandlerSelector for that, it is basically a multi-tenant scenario. What you could do is register everything in the container, and the SelectHandler method will be given an array of the registered handlers and you just have to return back which one you want to use based some context (e.g. ASP.NET context).